# Can a Finland Schengen visa get rejected if the invitation letter holder is unemployed?

Tags: schengen, finland, visa-rejections

My friend, a Finland citizen, sent me a invitation letter. I have applied and been to my interview, a few days ago. My friend was employed when I got the letter but now they are unemployed.

At this point I’m worried that my visa will get rejected. Is it possible for them to refuse my Schengen visa because of that? My friend is only providing me accommodation, the rest I got covered. I have been saving and looking forward to visiting Finland a very long time. I’m glad to have a friend who lives there to show me around. I have always been fond of Scandinavia, and would like to visit all of them one by one.

Anyhow if anyone has any answers please feel free to help me out with any kind of information. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

There's no rule saying that people who host international guests in their home need to be employed; it is hard to see how that would factor into the decision process for a visa.

Note well that "being invited by a citizen" does not in itself make visa officers any more likely to accept the application than they would be if you were just going for a tourist visit and staying in hotels.

All the invitation does is (a) explain that you have a plan for where to sleep and what that will cost you, and (b) help explain why you'd want to go to Finland in the first place. Your friend is not vouching for your honesty or plans, and his employment status does not matter for whether the invitation is a convincing explanation for (a) and (b).

While *some* explanation of each of these points required, they're usually not the sticking point of an application. It is much more important to the decision what your own circumstances in your home country are, since they are what must explain why you'd desire to *go back home* after the visit.